# Why Unique together is not preventing non unique values?

Tags: django

In my model combination of 2 fields (company, AM) should be unique

```
class Vendor_AM(models.Model):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    company = models.ForeignKey(V_Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    AM = models.ForeignKey(AM, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recomendedprice = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % ( self.id, self.AM.material.name , self.company.name )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("AM", "company"),)
```

For this reason, I have it defined in class Meta. But instead of form validation warning, I am getting an error on save. What could be the reason?

> IntegrityError at /vendor/manufacture_material/new/1/http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/company/company_am_details/1//
>   columns AM_id, company_id are not unique

UPDATE:
Form:

```
class Vendor_AMForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vendor_AM
        fields = [ 'AM','recomendedprice','is_active' ]
```

I am populating company directly in the view.

Comment: How are you validating this? What does your form look like?

Comment: did you migrate database properly?

Comment: I am not validating in the form . I assumed if I have unique together validation is taken care of .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form can only validate on the fields it actually contains. Since you've excluded `company` from the form, the combination of company and AM can't be validated.

Comment: Thank you. I started to think about it when you asked about a form. Added "except IntegrityError" when saving in view to catch it.